# Calculating Triple Integral

Tags: integration, surfaces

I have task : find volume of body limited by surface $(\frac{x}{a})^{2/3} + (\frac{y}{b})^{2/3} + (\frac{z}{c})^{2/3}$ = 1. I know that this task is about triple integral. But i have confused by such amazing surface. I also plotted graphic in Mathematica, however it didn't help. Maybe there is a substitution (to сylindrical coordinate system).

Comment: To my knowledge, this is a stretched 3D Astroid-type curve ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid ). Computing the arc length of $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ using parametrization $x = \cos^3(t), y = \sin^3(t)$ is a standard intro-calculus problem, so make sure you understand that before proceeding. I would also consider Gauß/Stokes theorems, so that you have to compute a surface integral instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write
\begin{align}
  x &= a(\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta))^3 \\
  y &= b(\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta))^3 \\
  z &= c(\rho\cos(\phi))^3,
\end{align}
for then, $(x/a)^{2/3} + (y/b)^{2/3} + (z/c)^{2/3} = \rho^2$. Furthermore, the Jacobian of change of variables is
$$648 \rho ^8 \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos ^2(\theta ) \sin^5(\varphi ) \cos ^2(\varphi ).$$
Thus, the volume can be computed as 
$$8\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{\frac{\pi
   }{2}}27 a b c \rho ^8 \cos ^2(\theta ) \cos
   ^2(\varphi ) \sin ^2(\theta ) \sin ^5(\varphi )
   \rho ^2d\varphi d\theta d\rho = 8\frac{9}{770} \pi  a b c.$$

---

You can also use the parametrization to visualize the object.  Here's what it looks like for $a=b=3$ and $c=2$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you were integrating over the volume

$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{z}{c}\right)^{2} \leq 1$$

you would use spherical polars with $x = ar\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y = br...$, $z = cr...$.

Now try and modify those so they fit your shape by taking the appropriate powers. Then calculate the Jacobian....

Comment: something like $x=ar^3sin^3{\theta}cos^3{\theta}$ and e.t.c?

Comment: Sounds reasonable (second $\theta$ is $\phi$)

Comment: @slmkarta Looks like you figured out the general idea while I was typing.  My answer has some more details, but not all.

Comment: @MarkMcClure yes, thank you anyway